# MailGun results in 401 forbidden using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mailgun

I am trying to send an email using mailgun and nodejs.
I took the code MailGun provides you and added my domain name and api key:

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
const DOMAIN = 'mail.mywebsite.com';
const mg = mailgun({apiKey: "this-is-myApiKey", domain: DOMAIN});
const data = {
    from: 'Support <support@mywebsite.com>',
    to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
};
mg.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(1, error);
    console.log(2, body);
});
```

This results in a 401 forbidden, but if I change to my sandbox domain name, then it works. Does anyone have some helpful tips to fix this?

```
mail.mywebsite.com = domain name set under sending domains
this-is-myApiKey = my private api key found here: https://app.mailgun.com/app/account/security/api_keys
```

Comment: If you are in the EU, add `host : "api.eu.mailgun.net"`. I have the same issue and I landed on your question, but I see you haven't added a EU host, maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to incorrect domain name of mailgun. Make sure that you are using the correct apikey and domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Might your Domain Name issue.

```
const mailgun = require("mailgun-js")({
    apiKey: 'your_api_key',
    domain: 'mg.yourDomainName.com'
});

const data = {
    from: "no-reply@yourDomainName.com",
    to: 'abcd@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
  };

mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
    console.log(body);
    if(!error) 
    res.status(200).json({
            message:"mail sent"
        })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in new mailgun api v3 you have to follow a different approach:

See my sample code below its working:

```
        var formData = require('form-data');
        const Mailgun = require('mailgun.js');
        const mailgun = new Mailgun(formData);
        const mg      = mailgun.client({
            username: 'api', 
            key: process.env.EMAIL_MAILGUN_API_KEY
        }); 
        
        mg.messages.create(process.env.EMAIL_MAILGUN_HOST, {
            from: "sender na,e <"+process.env.EMAIL_FROM+">",
            to: ["dan@dominic.com"],
            subject: "Verify Your Email",
            text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
            html: "<h1>"+req+"</h1>"
          })
          .then(msg => {
            console.log(msg);
            res.send(msg);
          }) // logs response data
          .catch(err => { 
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
          }); // logs any error
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to utilize the DNS name you verified.  i was trying to use my domain name (as everything in their documentation seems to dictate) and repeatedly faced HTTP 401 errors.  as soon as i changed `DOMAIN_NAME` to `VERIFIED_DNS_NAME` it worked.

e.g., my domain was `blahblah.com`.  however, the DNS name i verified was `mg.blahblah.com`.  when i changed my client to utilize that verified DNS name, it all worked